# how to show image from folder in Image Control using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show the image from folder in image control. But the image is not displaying. So help me how can I do this....

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "E:\\Application\\Users\\" + Imagename;
```

Comment: Please do not link code as an image. Also, questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Ganesh! Can you add the code that shows the initialization and declaration of `Imagename`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Users` is the folder in which the website resides, you would use relative paths.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Imagename;
```

Or if the image is located in a subfolder `images`

```
 Image1.ImageUrl = "/images/" + Imagename;
```

But if it is a folder outside the root of the website (and judging from the file path it could be) then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to the answer above, use relative path in the folder where your app is located and make some folder i.e Uploads. Point the folder like this.

```
 Image1.ImageUrl = "/Uploads/" + moneyReceiptUrl;
```

In the view display your image after it is saved in the folder.

```
<img src="../..@YourModel.Image1.ImageUrl" class="center-block">
```